# Join a json String values with new line

Tags: java, arrays, json, newline

I need to return json array each element in new line. but instead it's printing in one line. I tried using '/n' and space but it's not working.

```
String json = null;
//split cookie with delimiter to store in array
String wl[] = wishList.split("~");

//JSON RETURN VALUE
json = "[\"";
for(int i = 0; i < wl.length; ++i) {
    json +=  wl[i];
    //tried but didn't work
    //json.split("\n");
}
json += "\"]";
System.out.println(json);
```

so i tried cancatinating in for loop but it didn't work. 
I need out like this

```
1.abc
2.bcd
3.efg
```

but i'm getting this output

```
1.abcbcdefg
```

Comment: Did you read the [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) documentation? Just use `json += "\n"` or `json += wl[i] + "\n"`. Also your question's title leads me to believe that you think `json` is an array, it is not, it is a `String`.

Comment: Manually building JSON is an antipattern. Use a library like Jackson or Gson

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using '/n' and space but it's not working.

You should use `"\n"` in your JSON String to add new line and not `"/n"`, it is not the same thing. You should do the same thing for the regex pattern.

**3. Line Separator is '\n'**

> This means '\r\n' is also supported because trailing white space is ignored >when parsing JSON values.
>
> The last character in the file may be a line separator, and it will be
>   treated the same as if there was no line separator present.

Source : `http://jsonlines.org/`

**Edit**

A Json array has comma to separate values of the array and string should be between quotes or double quotes. but doesn't need "\" at the begining and at the end. 
You could get this String :

```
["abc",
"bcd",
"efg"]
```

with this code :

```
final String STRING_DOUBLE_QUOTE="\"";
String json = null;
// split cookie with delimiter to store in array
String wl[] = wishList.split("~");

// JSON RETURN VALUE
json = "[";
for (int i = 0; i < wl.length; ++i) {
    if (!json.equals("[")) {
      json += ",\n";
    }
    json += STRING_DOUBLE_QUOTE + wl[i] + STRING_DOUBLE_QUOTE;
}
json += "]";

System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: I would point that this is a typo, in the commented code, he used the correct `\n`. But I don't see why to use `\\n` instead of  `\n`.

Comment: No reason. Mistake from my part :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do (if I get it right) is to split a String on the `~` and creating a JSON array with it (one separate line).

Did you thought about simply replacing the character ?

```
String json = "[" + wishlist.replace("~", ",\n") + "]"; //Added a , to separated each elements
```

But if you want to do it yourself,

```
String json = "[";
for(int i = 0; i < wl.length; ++i) {
    json +=  wl[i] + ",\n";
}
json += "]";
```

You need to add the newLine character, not split it again.

Off course, as pointed, this should be done using a Library design to do it but here is a simple correction of you code.

PS : I didn't write the needed `\"` for redability. But this can be easily added in both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be on multiple lines, you're gonna have to save it in multiple elements i.e. an array.

Try this:

```
String wl[] = wishList.split("~");

for(int i = 0; i < wl.length; ++i){
     System.out.println(wl[i]);
}
```

Unsure if this is what you're asking for, but this is the answer to your written question